# Adding onClick handlers to items dynamically added to DOM from object

Tags: javascript, jquery

i need to add a click handler to items dynamically inserted to DOM using jQuery, objects come from a service that returns an object, so i basically have this (example object):

Object:

```
var items = {
    18: {
        content: "<div id=\"content18\"  > <img src=\"http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png\">  </div>"
    },
    10: {
        content: "<div id=\"content10\"  > <img src=\"http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png\">  </div>"
    },
    34: {
        content: "<div id=\"content34\"  > <img src=\"http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png\">  </div>"
    },
    2: {
        content: "<div id=\"content2\"  > <img src=\"http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png\">  </div>"
    },
    29: {
        content: "<div id=\"content29\"  > <img src=\"http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png\">  </div>"
    },
    56: {
        content: "<div id=\"content56\"  > <img src=\"http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png\">  </div>"
    },
    50: {
        content: "<div id=\"content50\"  > <img src=\"http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png\">  </div>"
    },
    59: {
        content: "<div id=\"content59\"  > <img src=\"http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png\">  </div>"
    },
    46: {
        content: "<div id=\"content46\"  > <img src=\"http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png\">  </div>"
    },
    38: {
        content: "<div id=\"content38\"  > <img src=\"http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png\">  </div>"
    },
    30: {
        content: "<div id=\"content30\"  > <img src=\"http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png\">  </div>"
    },
    12: {
        content: "<div id=\"content12\"  > <img src=\"http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png\">  </div>"
    },
    61: {
        content: "<div id=\"content61\"  > <img src=\"http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png\">  </div>"
    },
    14: {
        content: "<div id=\"content14\"  > <img src=\"http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png\">  </div>"
    }
};
```

And then i add them to the DOM and (try) to add a click handler for each added item:

```
var rankingItems = $(".rankingitem"), i = 0, element;
for (var index in items) { 
        $(rankingItems[i]).after(items[index].content);
        // crete listeners
        element = $("#content"+index).click(function() {
            console.log(index);
        });
        console.log(element);
        i++;
}
```

Problem is that no matter what i try, the click handler always get the last item in the object, but does not assign a click handler for each. Maybe i'm missing something here?

Added a JS Bin example:

http://jsbin.com/batadosepara/1/edit

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `index` will always refer to the last one in the list because of how callbacks work. Wrap the listener creation in an IIFE to get around that:

```
(function(i){
    element = $("#content"+i).click(function() {
        console.log(adIndex));
    });
})(index);
```

Take a look at this fiddle to get an idea of how it works:
http://jsfiddle.net/7o7bhkey/

Comment: Wow, this worked, still don't exactly understand why or how, but works, here's the edited fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7o7bhkey/4/ Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

try this, on() function is good for DOM elements that is newly appended

```
  var rankingItems = $(".rankingitem"), i = 0, element;
 for (var index in items) { 
         $(rankingItems[i]).after(items[index].content);

        });
         console.log(element);
        i++;


 $("div[id^='content']").on("click",function(){
     console.log($(this).text());
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('body').on('click', 'div[id~="content"]', function(){})
```